# NotificationManager.cancel() doesn't work: Notification isn't removed

Tags: android, android-service, foreground, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I've been trying to remove a persistent Notification set by a Service using:

```
startForeground(1337, notification);
```

The code I'm using to cancel it:

```
NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nManager.cancel(1337);  // cancel existing service notification, doesn't take effect
nManager.cancelAll(); //surpluous, but also doesn't take effect
```

To clarify why I am doing this: the Service starts with a default persistent Notification. When my app runs, it needs to replace this Notification with another. Using `notify()` on the existing Notification works perfectly, however, I need it to show the ticker text for the new Notification as well. This is why I decided to remove the existing Notification (using the code above), create a new one, and then I call `startForeground()` again and pass the new Notification to it, so my Service persists.

Comment: You're trying to remove a notification which was started from a different application?

Comment: no, it's the same application

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you're issuing the Notification in an indirect way by using `startForeground()`.  You can't just cancel that Notification for the same reason the system insists on you providing a Notification when starting a foreground Service.  As long as your foreground Service is running, that Notification will be there.

In most cases, Services really shouldn't be in the foreground.  If you can use a normal priority for your Service, then you can start and stop your Notification normally.

If you're actually doing something that truly does require a foreground Service, and if you really want to show the user a ticker text, I believe your only option is to issue another Notification.

Comment: they should really put this in the documentation or have it throw an error when this is attempted...

Answer (score 7):

You can always remove notification from a foreground service by callng stopForeground(boolean removeNotification). Then a service exits his foregroundState and once again can be killed by the system when the memory is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could update the notification by passing in an empty Builder.

```
if(showNotification){
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_spotify_white_24dp)
            .setTicker("Playing Now")
            .setContentTitle("Spotify")
            .setContentText("Preview");
    return mBuilder;
}else{
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    return mBuilder;
}
```