# Can I start a foreground service without setOngoing(true)?

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service

I do have a service which is started in foreground:

```
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setTicker(message)
    .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
    .setContentText(message)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .build()
startForeground(Notifications.Id.RUNNING, notification)
```

Note that I am **not** using `setOngoing(true)`.

I found some examples and answers here at StackOveflow and some people are using `setOngoing(true)` and some don't. Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6397982/1945754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47549638/1945754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20142620/1945754

Also, [the Android documentation says](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground):

> A foreground service is a service that the user is actively aware of
>   and is not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory. A
>   foreground service must provide a notification for the status bar,
>   which is placed under the Ongoing heading. **This means that the
>   notification cannot be dismissed unless the service is either stopped
>   or removed from the foreground**.

And, inside the documentation, the `setOngoing(true)` is not being set:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification =
          new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_DEFAULT_IMPORTANCE)
    .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
    .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_message))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setTicker(getText(R.string.ticker_text))
    .build();

startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

### Question

What is the impact omitting the `setOngoing(true)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start a Service and run it in foreground with `startForeground(int, Notification)`, the notification you passed get's the flag [FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE) (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-mr1-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ServiceRecord.java#493)).

Then, before your notification will actually be posted into the status bar `NotificationManagerService` checks if `FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE` is set and if so it will add the flag [FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT) (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-mr1-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java#3891)) which is the same flag that will be set when you manually use `setOngoing(true)` (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-mr1-release/core/java/android/app/Notification.java#3434)).

Comment: Is it possible though to allow the user to dismiss the notification of the foreground service just like any other notification, which would trigger the service and so we can close the service?